# My 3D Shader wont render light direction correctly opengl/c++/glsl

Tags: opengl, c++, glsl, glm

This is what I'm doing:

vertex shader:

```
#version 400
layout ( location = 0 ) in vec3 vertex_position;
layout ( location = 1 ) in vec3 vertex_normal;

uniform mat4 ModelViewMatrix; //model
uniform mat3 NormalMatrix; //transpose(inverse(model)))
uniform mat4 priv_mat; //projection*view*model

out vec3 normal;
out vec3 position;

void main()
{
  normal=normalize(NormalMatrix*vertex_normal);
  position=vec3(ModelViewMatrix*vec4(vertex_position,1.0));
  gl_Position=priv_mat*vec4(vertex_position,1.0);
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 400
in vec3 normal;
in vec3 position;

uniform vec4 LightPosition; // light position: vec4(0,0,0,1); 
uniform vec3 LightIntensity;

uniform vec3 Kd;            // Diffuse reflectivity
uniform vec3 Ka;            // Ambient reflectivity
uniform vec3 Ks;            // Specular reflectivity
uniform float Shininess;    // Shininess

vec3 ads( ){
    vec3 n = normal;
    vec3 s = normalize( vec3(LightPosition) - position ); 
    vec3 v = normalize( vec3(-position)); 
    vec3 r = reflect( -s, n );
return 
    LightIntensity * 
    ( Ka + 
    Kd * max( dot(s, n), 0.0 ) +  
    Ks * pow( max( dot(r,v), 0.0 ), Shininess ) );
}

void main()
{
     gl_FragColor = vec4(ads(), 1.0);
}
```

But when I run it, I get this:

[image: shouldnt the light be correct?]

Where the light doesnt just come from the wrong spot, but it also doesnt change when I move the planet around, like so

[image: I can spin the asteroid, but the light doesnt come from where it should]

The diffuse value somehow gets the wrong direction? According to the example given ([page 90](http://people.inf.elte.hu/plisaai/pdf/David%20Wolff%20-%20OpenGL%204.0%20Shading%20Language%20Cookbook%20(2).pdf)), the diffuse is calculated by getting the dot(s,n), where s is lightposition-position, and position is (view*model*vertex_position). But like you can see, the result doesnt shade the direction correctly.

Solution: The answer was matrix confusion all along. The problem was the ModelViewMatrix, and that It didnt have to be multiplied with view before being sent to the shader. The rest is just correct. Basically I was putting the "position" in the wrong space. Not multiplying with view before sending to the shader fixes it.

Comment: You can use the coupling operator to convert stuff to vec3. Instead of vec3(s), you can use s.xyz

Comment: And you should really store directional lights as directions instead of position

Comment: I found the answer, I am multiplying with the wrong values. ModelViewMatrix was multiplied with view, when it shouldnt be